# Mock redux thunk API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library, redux-thunk

I'm just trying to make a mock response in my thunk handler, but I can't spot the place I did wrong. I have added some comments in the redux controller to get a clear view. can someone help me to get what I want?

component

```
const handleRequest = () => {
        setProductSaving(true)

        const callback = (response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setProductSaving(false)
                setProductRequested(true)
            }
        }

        const productInfo = {
            // product input
        }

        dispatch(requestProduct(productInfo))
    }
```

Thunk controller

```
export const requestProduct = ({ smeId, userId, requestPayload, callback, approveeUserId, isApprovee = false}) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        
        try {
            let endpointUrl = `/product/${smeId}/user/${userId}`;

            if (isApprovee) {
                endpointUrl = `/product/${smeId}/approver/${userId}?approveeUserId=${approveeUserId}`;
            }

            const response = await axios.put(endpointUrl, requestPayload);
            // NOTE: should mock above response when calling
            // CURRENT => response is 'undefined' here. so below code doesn't run on test environment
            // REQUIRED => to run below code with the mock response

            if(response.status === 200) {
                dispatch({
                    type: NOTIFY_STATUS,
                    payload: {
                        message: response.data.message,
                        variant: 'success',
                    },
                })
            }

            callback?.(response)
            
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: NOTIFY_STATUS,
                payload: {
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                },
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Test file

```
jest.mock('axios');

test('should be able to request product', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render( <Router>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={techpathTheme}>
                    <ProductCard product={product} />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Provider>
        </Router>)

        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('requestbtn')) // this will trigger the action in component 

        const mockedResponse = {
            data: { message: "SMEProductTagAddedSuccessfully"},
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK',
        };

        axios.put.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mock the axios.put before you fire the event. Otherwise it will call the original axios behaviour.

```js
jest.mock('axios');

test('should be able to request product', () => {
        const mockedResponse = {
            data: { message: "SMEProductTagAddedSuccessfully"},
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK',
        };

        axios.put.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);

        const { getByTestId } = render( <Router>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={techpathTheme}>
                    <ProductCard product={product} />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Provider>
        </Router>)

        fireEvent.click(getByTestId('requestbtn')) // this will trigger the action in component 
    })
```

Comment: Yes, you got the point. it's working. thanks Petkov